# Spatial Query tool for Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, jquery, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I’ve using Mapbox Studio to create a web map that’ll allow a user to interact with some basic parcel data.  I’m looking to add a basic spatial query tool for the user so that they can apply spatial filters such as: Parcel_Size >=’5000’ or Zone = ‘Residential’. Here’s an example of ArcExplorers Query Tool which has the functionality I'm looking for.  [image: image of ArcExplorer’s query tool]

I'm new at web mapping and assuming I'm going to need to incorporate some JavaScript in order to make this work.

Does such tool exist that will allow me to add it to my Mapbox map?

I checked out [Mapbox JS](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/), but the examples I'm seeing are a little to basic (toggle buttons, search boxes). Of course I could be completely missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you'll need to build a JavaScript app for this. You can see a similar filter example at https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/timeline-animation/, and review the `setFilter` documentation at https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setfilter